# Access json data using angular.forEach

Tags: angularjs, json

How should i access URL json array data using angular.forEace.
i am trying to get data but giving some error please check below code i have added

```
[{
   "flightsDepartur":[
        {
          "fare":"9,000",
          "route":[
            {
              "source":"Delhi",
            }
             ],
         },
     ]
  }]

        $http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.allData = response;
         },function(dataStatus){
             console.log(dataStatus);
         });

    angular.forEach($scope.allData, function(flidata) {
        angular.forEach(flidata[0].flightsDepartur, function(flidatIn) {
            console.log(flidatIn.fare);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

check the below to get fare and route data

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = [{
   "flightsDepartur":[
        {
          "fare":"9,000",
          "route":[
            {
              "source":"Delhi",
            }
             ],
         },
     ]
  }];
  angular.forEach($scope.name, function(k,v) {
        angular.forEach(k, function(k,v) {
       console.log(k[0].fare);
       console.log(k[0].route[0].source)
    });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: i have list of data i want to get data using forEach

Comment: please provide list

Comment: Every time i have to add k[0], this is not good

"route":[
       {
       "source":"Delhi",
       "destination":"Pune"
       }
    ],
            "timing":[
               {
                  "depart":"10:00 AM",
                  "arrival":"12:00 AM"
               }
            ],

Comment: see in question you asked for  console.log(flidatIn.fare); only...later added "how should i access my 'route' data".....and nnow your asking something else...so i suggesst you to please provide all your requirements at once and please provide the sufficient data acc to your requirement

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are assigning values to `$scope.allData` inside a promise. since the javascript asynchronous before the data being assign to `$scope.allData` for each loop start to execute. at that time `$scope.allData`  was undefined. so it produces an error.

create a function and call that inside the promise to prevent the error

```
$http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
      $scope.allData = response.data;
      callLoop()
 },function(dataStatus){
      console.log(dataStatus);
 });

function callLoop(){
    angular.forEach($scope.allData, function(flidata) {
        angular.forEach(flidata.flightsDepartur, function(flidatIn) {
            console.log(flidatIn.fare);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
angular.forEach(flidata[0].flightsDepartur, function(flidatIn) {..
```

to

```
angular.forEach(flidata.flightsDepartur, function(flidatIn) {..
```

and when using `then` function to get response change to this.

```
 $http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.allData = response.data;
     },function(dataStatus){
         console.log(dataStatus);
     });
```

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.allData = [{
    "flightsDepartur": [{
      "fare": "9,000",
      "route": [{
        "source": "Delhi",
      }],
    }, ]
  }]

  angular.forEach($scope.allData, function(flidata) {
    angular.forEach(flidata.flightsDepartur, function(flidatIn) {
      console.log(flidatIn.fare);
      console.log(flidatIn.route[0].source);
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="ctrl">

</div>
```

Comment: i have change but how should i access my 'route' data

Comment: by `flidatIn.route` or `flidatIn.route[0].source`

Comment: I am using this but not getting anything
angular.forEach($scope.allData, function(flidata) {
    //console.log(flidata);
   angular.forEach(flidata.flightsDepartur, function(flidatIn) {
    console.log(flidatIn);
    
   });
   
    });